# Как установить ограничения для обеспечения безопасности базы данных Firebase

Tags: база-данных, swift, безопасность, firebase, firebase-database

Я пытаюсь реализовать систему, в которой игрок может зарегистрироваться, играть  и получать очки. Как сделать так, чтобы баланс очков, который хранится в его аккаунте, не смог взломать сам игрок или другой игрок? Это должны быть ограничения в коде или в базе данных? У меня есть база данных, но правила установлены по умолчанию, мне кажется, их надо поменять.

Код занесения очков в базу выглядит следующим образом:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseDatabase

let ref = Database.database().reference()

let userID : String = (Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid)!

class GameCoins: UIViewController, UnityAdsDelegate
{

    @IBOutlet weak var currencyLabel: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {


        ref.child("users").child(userID).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
            // Get user value
            let snapshotValue = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
            let balance = snapshotValue!["coins"] as! Int
            self.currencyLabel.text = "\(String(describing: balance))"
        }) { (error) in
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
        super.viewDidLoad()
        }


    func gameMoveDidFinish(_ placementId: String) {
        if (state != .skipped) {
            ref.child("users").child(userID).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
                // Get user value
                let snapshotValue = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
                var balance = snapshotValue!["coins"] as! Int
                balance += 1
                ref.root.child("users").child(userID).updateChildValues(["coins": balance])

                self.currencyLabel.text = "\(String(describing: balance))"
            }) { (error) in
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
    }

}
```

База и правила приведены ниже:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null"
  }
}
```

Знаю, что если хранить очки в NSUserDefaults, то их легко можно взломать, поэтому используют keychain. Я получается храню данные на Firebase, но в теме какие следует поставить ограничение на запись и чтение разбираюсь очень плохо. Буду благодарна за любые рекомендации и поправки, хочу разобраться, как обеспечить безопасность и игроку, и приложению от взлома.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не знаю Swift, но знаком с Firebase и сталкивался с такой задачей, поэтому может мой совет будет полезен. Обычно, когда используют Firebase Database для игр, либо приложений с необходимостью добавления сложной бекенд логики, арендуют сторонний сервер. Только этому серверу можно писать данные в Firebase. Сам клиент может только читать базу данных.

Стандартный запрос проходит такой путь:

1. Клиент отправляет запрос на сервер.
2. Запрос проверяется этим сервером (например, может ли игрок получить сразу 5000 очков, как написано в запросе, когда за победу дают только 10 очков).
3. При одобрении запроса этот сервер пишет данные в Firebase Database, в случае неодобрения ничего не пишется.
4. У клиента вызывается коллбек от Firebase с новыми данными.

В правилах Firebase в таком случае на **write** просто **false**.

Если нужны туториалы, как дать права стороннему серверу на запись в Firebase, как обрабатывать запросы и т.п., можете начать [отсюда](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/mobile/mobile-app-backend-services), у Google App Engine есть бесплатный период, который поможет вам не только разобраться в реализации, но и посмотреть на рабочий продукт. А как разберетесь уже будете думать о смене хостинга, если захотите.

---

P.S. В такой связке вы получаете удобства от Firebase, сэкономите много времени, т.к. многое за вас делает Firebase, но возможно это будет более накладно по деньгам, чем если бы реализовывали все с одним сервером. Советую так же посмотреть на цены и правильно взвесить "за" и "против" перед продакшном.
Еще хотел бы отметить то, что Google App Engine не поддерживает tcp/ip и udp/ip, поэтому, если ваша игра динамичная, вам придется думать что-то другое, например, полностью мигрировать на amazon web services, т.к. http может быть слишком медленным для вашего случая.

Comment: Спасибо, а если я вот, например, задаю в коде начальное число очков 0 - setValue(["coins": 0, "email" : self.emailTextField.text!]), установила мои ограничения(которые в вопросе) и задала функцию, которая каждый раз при нажатии увеличивает это число очков "coins" на 1. При этом, сама я в базе поменять это значение никак не могу, потому что оно уже задано и меняется только при выполнении функции. Получается, у пользователя все равно в этот момент может быть какой-то доступ, например, чтобы поменять начальное значение или число, которое прибавляется к "coins", если он взломает код?

Comment: или получается он может просто отследить передаваемое на сервер значение монет и поменять его?

Comment: @Diana клиент может менять значения любых ваших переменных, когда захочет, в том числе и переменную balance. GameGuardian (приложуха для взлома), например, может игроку в этом помочь. Перехватить запрос и редактировать его, чтобы переотправить, у пользователя не получится, т.к. Firebase шифрует сообщения на сервер с помощью TLS.

Comment: надеялась iOS в этом смысле безопаснее(игра только на iOS), но,видимо, придется подумать, как здесь тоже реализовать эту схему через сторонний сервер

Comment: @Diana если переменная balance у вас существует только на момент инкрементирования значения с базы данных и при этом нет никаких других специфичных записей вроде этой, которую надо защитить, то можете остаться с Firebase. Чтобы поймать этот момент, нужно будет стороннее по, тк вроде GameGuardian не имеет опций для таких случаев. А значит, школьнику будет не под силу взломать ваше приложение. А более сложные моменты будете решать, когда заработаете деньги с приложения.

Comment: Знаю, что тут нельзя говорить спасибо, но все равно спасибо вам огромное за детальное объяснение!